# MVVMCross StarterPack not installing from Nuget in fresh PCL

Tags: mvvmcross, portable-class-library

I've created a fresh Portable Class Library in Visual Studio 2012 (as per the instructions)

[image]

*I've also tried lowering the Target Framework to .Net 4*

I then proceed to run

```
PM> Install-Package MvvmCross.HotTuna.StarterPack
```

But it's throwing an error

> Attempting to resolve dependency 'MvvmCross.HotTuna.MvvmCrossLibraries
>   (≥ 3.0.10)'. Attempting to resolve dependency
>   'MvvmCross.HotTuna.CrossCore (≥ 3.0.10)'. Attempting to resolve
>   dependency 'MvvmCross.PortableSupport (≥ 3.0.10)'. Installing
>   'MvvmCross.PortableSupport 3.0.10'. Successfully installed
>   'MvvmCross.PortableSupport 3.0.10'. Installing
>   'MvvmCross.HotTuna.CrossCore 3.0.10'. Successfully installed
>   'MvvmCross.HotTuna.CrossCore 3.0.10'. Installing
>   'MvvmCross.HotTuna.MvvmCrossLibraries 3.0.10'. Successfully installed
>   'MvvmCross.HotTuna.MvvmCrossLibraries 3.0.10'. Installing
>   'MvvmCross.HotTuna.StarterPack 3.0.10'. Successfully installed
>   'MvvmCross.HotTuna.StarterPack 3.0.10'. Adding
>   'MvvmCross.PortableSupport 3.0.10' to FutureStateDemo.Core.
>   Uninstalling 'MvvmCross.PortableSupport 3.0.10'. Successfully
>   uninstalled 'MvvmCross.PortableSupport 3.0.10'. Install failed.
>   Rolling back... Could not install package 'MvvmCross.PortableSupport
>   3.0.10'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'portable-win+net45+sl40+wp', but the package does not contain
>   any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

What does it take to get this starter pack up and running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure MvvmCross no longer has support for Windows Phone 7, so you can't target that in the PCL.

You have to pick the Windows Phone 7.5 target framework instead.

Comment: Ah, that works. I had to actually just boosted it to `.Net 4.5` and `Windows Phone 8`.