# Problems compiling MvvmCross TipCalc sample

Tags: mvvmcross

I am trying to run the MvvmCross TipCalc sample. Using NuGet on TipCalc.UI.Droid to resolve references works OK. I then try to do same on TipCalc.Core and get:

```
Adding 'MvvmCross.PortableSupport 3.0.13' to TipCalc.Core.
Could not install package 'MvvmCross.PortableSupport 3.0.13'. You are trying 
to install this package into a project that targets 'portable-win+net40+sl40+wp',
but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that 
are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

Shouldn't the project just be ready to go for NuGet and it should "just work"? I am newbie to NuGet and MvvmCross. I am on Win7, VS.NET 2012, NuGet 2.7.40911.225, and latest [MvvmCross-Tutorials](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials) from GitHub.

Comment: I had to download the binaries from their [MVVMCross-Binaries](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Binaries/) page (can't remember exactly what it's called). NuGet wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem will probably be in 'net40' and 'wp' platforms you've included - for PCL reasons we need a minimum of 'net45' and wp75' used - see the chart in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx for the fact that 'net40' doesn't currently support Mvvm Types (e.g. `INotifyPropertyChanged`).

If it helps, my current development setup here has remained unchanged since March - it's still http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/my-current-pcl-setup-in-visual-studio.html

> Shouldn't the project just be ready to go for NuGet and it should "just work"?

The process towards getting all the tooling for PCLs, nuget, VS, XS, etc working across all the platforms has been slow, hard work.... it is happening and it will one day 'just work' but it continues to take time and lots of work from lots of people.

There are still open workitems within nuget and within Xamarin - e.g. http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/2926 - which people are working on; some of the MS legal hurdles have recently been cleared (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/10/14/portable-class-library-pcl-now-available-on-all-platforms.aspx); and technically things change on the Xamarin side with almost every Alpha release. But it is hard to get definitive answers on when things will be 100% ready and will "just work".

The good news is that:

- with the 2 XML files from http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/my-current-pcl-setup-in-visual-studio.html I and plenty of others have been happily using PCLs and nuget for the last 6 months or so.
- progress is still moving forwards

---

Some of these Q&A's may also help:

- [MVVMCross StarterPack not installing from Nuget in fresh PCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18678457/mvvmcross-starterpack-not-installing-from-nuget-in-fresh-pcl)
- [Can't install MVVMCross on PCL project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17906287/cant-install-mvvmcross-on-pcl-project)
- [MvvMCross 3.0.6 Nuget package installation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529794/mvvmcross-3-0-6-nuget-package-installation-issue)
- [Adding MvvmCross nuget package reference to PCL failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254455/adding-mvvmcross-nuget-package-reference-to-pcl-failed)
- [Getting PCL, Mvvmcross, Nuget and Xamarin Studio to play "nice" on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17653208/getting-pcl-mvvmcross-nuget-and-xamarin-studio-to-play-nice-on-mac)

Comment: Changing the profile worked, thanks Stuart! Perhaps if you have time you can change the profile for TipCalc.Core and other samples where appropriate.